# How to detect & configure a upnp USB to serial adaptor for RXTX development in Java

Tags: serial-port, dmesg, minicom

I ordered a [TRENDnet TU-S9](http://www.trendnet.com/products/proddetail.asp?prod=265_TU-S9) and and plugged it into my system. I heard this is plug and play and that it works on Ubuntu. I'm wondering how to determine which port identifier this USB to serial adapter will register on when its plugged in.

When I go to `/dev` and do `ls -a | grep ttyS` I get:

```
ttyS0
ttyS1
...
all 32 tty entries...
...
ttyS31
```

So I'm guessing these are all placeholders and maybe my serial port is mapped to `/dev/ttyS0`? How would I go about figuring this out if this is a upnp device?

**UPDATE**

I've been trying `setserial -g` to try identifying my upnp USB serial port but nothing is returned. Also tried installing and using minicom which defaults to `/dev/ttyS8` but not sure if that is because it detected something or that is the default port it tries to read on.

When I do `dmesg | grep tty` I get this:

```
[50429.859191] pl2303 ttyUSB0: pl2303 converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[50447.038572] usb 3-1: pl2303 converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

I'm basically trying to connect to the serial port using a java application and the rxtx library. I'm wondering if I can just connect with serial port id of: `/dev/ttyUSB0` or would I need to connect to on of the `/dev/ttyS*` ports and identify the port? If that is the case I have 32 of those so would be nice to find out which one to use.

Comment: Revised, is this more appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

I think a simple answer is:

```
dmesg | grep tty
```

to identify the device.

At this point I was able to use minicom to communicate with my external devices on `/dev/ttyUSB0`.